# SVG file can't convert to an expected image in Itext7

Tags: java, itext7

I have an SVG file, when I used `SvgConverter.convertToImage` to convert it as an image and added into a PDF document, the output image isn't as expected. The image stroke size became much bigger than that of the SVG file. My `svg` plugin version is 7.1.9. How to fix such issue?
What's the expected chart:[image: expected Chart]
The actual output in pdf is:[image: actual chart]

```java
SvgConverterProperties props = new SvgConverterProperties();
FontProvider provider = new FontProvider();
provider.addFont(FontProgramFactory.createFont("fontname"));
props.setFontProvider(provider);
Image pdfImage = SvgConverter.convertToImage(new FileInputStream(imagePath), pdfDoc, props);
```

The svg contents:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="17px" height="21px"
  viewBox="0 0 17 21" enable-background="new 0 0 17 21" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
   <g>
    <defs>
     <path id="SVGID_3_" d="M12.435,6.162c0,0.496-0.371,0.903-0.867,0.946l0.036,0.396c0.699-0.065,1.225-0.64,1.225-1.343H12.435z
      "/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible" fill="#2156A3"/>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
     <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>

     <rect x="9.591" y="4.183" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#2156A3" stroke="#518428" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="5.218" height="5.297"/>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible" fill="none" stroke="#2156A3" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <defs>
     <path id="SVGID_5_" d="M11.17,4.509c0-0.357,0.289-0.646,0.647-0.646c0.357,0,0.647,0.289,0.647,0.646
      c0,0.356-0.29,0.648-0.647,0.648C11.459,5.157,11.17,4.866,11.17,4.509 M10.774,4.509c0,0.575,0.466,1.043,1.043,1.043
      c0.576,0,1.043-0.468,1.043-1.043c0-0.577-0.467-1.043-1.043-1.043C11.24,3.467,10.774,3.933,10.774,4.509"/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible" fill="#2156A3"/>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
     <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>
     <rect x="8.796" y="1.489" clip-path="url(#SVGID_6_)" fill="#2156A3" stroke="#2156A3" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="6.041" height="6.043"/>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible" fill="none" stroke="#2156A3" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
   </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please give more detail... what does it show? Can you attach a screenshot? Please try to describe what the expected output should be and how it differs from your actual output.

Comment: Please also share the svg to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: I updated with charts and svg contents.@mkl

Comment: It seems like "stroke-width="0.25"" attribute is missing in iText7

Answer (score 0):

iText 7 in current version (7.1.10) processes `stroke-width` incorrectly if it's specified in `<use>` elements (instead of in `<path>` elements which are referenced from that `<use>`). As a workaround you can specify `stroke-width` directly on `path` elements like that:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="17px" height="21px"
  viewBox="0 0 17 21" enable-background="new 0 0 17 21" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
   <g>
    <defs>
     <path stroke-width="0.25" id="SVGID_3_" d="M12.435,6.162c0,0.496-0.371,0.903-0.867,0.946l0.036,0.396c0.699-0.065,1.225-0.64,1.225-1.343H12.435z
      "/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible" fill="#2156A3"/>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
     <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>

     <rect x="9.591" y="4.183" clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)" fill="#2156A3" stroke="#518428" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="5.218" height="5.297"/>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  overflow="visible" fill="none" stroke="#2156A3"  stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <defs>
     <path stroke-width="0.25" id="SVGID_5_" d="M11.17,4.509c0-0.357,0.289-0.646,0.647-0.646c0.357,0,0.647,0.289,0.647,0.646
      c0,0.356-0.29,0.648-0.647,0.648C11.459,5.157,11.17,4.866,11.17,4.509 M10.774,4.509c0,0.575,0.466,1.043,1.043,1.043
      c0.576,0,1.043-0.468,1.043-1.043c0-0.577-0.467-1.043-1.043-1.043C11.24,3.467,10.774,3.933,10.774,4.509"/>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible" fill="#2156A3"/>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
     <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>
     <rect x="8.796" y="1.489" clip-path="url(#SVGID_6_)" fill="#2156A3" stroke="#2156A3" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="6.041" height="6.043"/>
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_"  overflow="visible" fill="none" stroke="#2156A3"  stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
   </g>
</g>
</svg>
```